# Turn list of different length vectors into a `tibble`

Tags: r, list, purrr, tibble

I currently have a list of character vectors that are different lengths. Like this:

```
list(
  c('this','is','first'),
  c('this','is','second','it','longer'),
  c('this is a list','that is length 2')
)
```

I'd like to combine all the elements of each vector in the list into a single row in a `tibble`. Like this:

```
data_frame(column_1 =
             c('this is first',
               'this is second it longer',
               'this is a list that is length 2'))
```

I'd like to use base R or packages from the `tidyverse` if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `purrr` and `stringr`

```
x <- list(
  c('this','is','first'),
  c('this','is','second','it','longer'),
  c('this is a list','that is length 2')
)

tibble(column1= map_chr(x, str_flatten, " "))
```

Note that `str_flatten` is new to `stringr_1.3.0`

This could also be easily done with base R (no tidyverse functions)

```
data.frame(column1 = sapply(x, paste, collapse= " "))
```