# Convert list of named vectors of different length to tibble

Tags: r

I have the following list

```
example <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3),
                b = c(2, 3),
                c = c(3, 4, 5, 6))
```

that I'd like to transform into the following tibble

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 a         2
3 a         3
4 b         2
5 b         3
6 c         3
7 c         4
8 c         5
9 c         6
```

I've found multiple StackOverflow questions on this subject like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201305/how-to-convert-a-list-consisting-of-vector-of-different-lengths-to-a-usable-data), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937527/turn-list-of-different-length-vectors-into-a-tibble) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684158/convert-a-uneven-list-to-a-data-frame), but none is adressing this particular case where the name of the vector is not expected to become a column name.

I managed to achieve the desired result with a good old loop like below, but I'm looking for a faster and more elegant way.

```
library(dplyr)

example_list <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3),
                     b = c(2, 3),
                     c = c(3, 4, 5, 6))

example_tibble <- tibble()

for (i in 1:length(example_list)) {
  example_tibble <- example_tibble %>% 
    bind_rows(as_tibble(example_list[[i]]) %>% 
                mutate(name = names(example_list)[[i]]))
}

example_tibble <- example_tibble %>% 
  relocate(name)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `stack`

```
> stack(example)
  values ind
1      1   a
2      2   a
3      3   a
4      2   b
5      3   b
6      3   c
7      4   c
8      5   c
9      6   c
```

Comment: That's great: fast & simple! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can

Comment: `stack(example)[,2:1] |> setNames(c("name", "value"))`

Answer (score 2):

```r
example <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3),
                b = c(2, 3),
                c = c(3, 4, 5, 6))
library(tidyverse)
enframe(example) %>% 
  unnest(value)

#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1
#> 2 a         2
#> 3 a         3
#> 4 b         2
#> 5 b         3
#> 6 c         3
#> 7 c         4
#> 8 c         5
#> 9 c         6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>