# R - list to dataframe in certain format?

Tags: r

I have data structured like this (but with c. 1000 or so items):

```
x <- list("test1" = c("a","b","c"),
          "test2" = c("x","y"))

> x
$test1
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$test2
[1] "x" "y"
```

I'd like to structure it like this:

```
     l1 l2
1 test1  a
2 test1  b
3 test1  c
4 test2  x
5 test2  y
```

Ideally in a fairly fast/efficient way as my actual list is quite large

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list of named vectors of different length to tibble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840608/convert-list-of-named-vectors-of-different-length-to-tibble)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
x <- list("test1" = c("a","b","c"),
          "test2" = c("x","y"))

stack(x)
```

Comment: similar `stack` question was asked just few hours ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840608/convert-list-of-named-vectors-of-different-length-to-tibble

Answer (score 0):

Using `enframe`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(x, name = 'l1', value = 'l2') %>% 
    unnest(l2)
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  l1    l2   
  <chr> <chr>
1 test1 a    
2 test1 b    
3 test1 c    
4 test2 x    
5 test2 y
```